# Display unobtrusive message for jquery autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to find an answer for my problem.  I have a simple jQuery autocomplete field and the entry is required by the model.  But when I check it with the validation method it is not highlighted.

```
 <tr>
            <td>
                <b style="color:red">*</b>Find User ID or Enter New:<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="users" class="userModel" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.UserId, new { @id = "txtUserId" })
            </td>
        </tr>

 $("#users").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'data': request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUsers")',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            value: obj
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            neworold = "old";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUser")',
                data: { userid: ui.item.label },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#txtUserName").val(data.UserName);
                    $("#ddlUserRole").val(data.UserRole);
                    $("#chkUserAdmin").prop("checked", data.Admin);
                    $("#chkUserTrans").prop("checked", data.Trans);
                    $("#chkUserReports").prop("checked", data.Reports);
                    $("#txtUserId").val(data.UserId);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    var err = xhr.responseText;
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $("#users").autocomplete('search', $("#users").val());
    }).blur(function () {
        var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
        keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
        $(this).trigger(keyEvent);
        if (neworold != "old") {
            $("#txtUserId").val($("#users").val());
        }
    });
     if (!$("#userForm").valid()) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Which control? All you have shown is a hidden input and hidden inputs are not validated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The input element "users" is filled from the autocomplete method, but when nothing is in the field the validation does not highlight it nor fail when the field is blank.

Comment: Again, which control are your referring to? The only control you have shown is a hidden input for property `UserId` and a pointless `ValidationMessageFor()` associated with that property (since by default hidden inputs are not validated)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - OK, I get that hidden inputs are not validated.  How do I then make sure the user has put something in that autocomplete field or selected one of the displayed values?

Comment: What autocomplete field? Are you referring to the `<input id="users" ../>` which is just manual html? It does not have any `data-val-` attributes for unobtrusive validation. What are you expecting?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - obviously I don't know.  When the user selects something or types in something, the autocomplete functionality, with 'select' or 'blur' fills the hidden field with the value.  This works fine when sending to the controller but if it is empty I have to catch it in the controller not on the page.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does you model have a property named `Users`? Does that property have the `[RequiredAttribute]`? You need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Users)` and you should include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Users)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thank you, I see my mistake.  I should have used a standard textboxfor field, and used the autocomplete for that.  It work now.  If you post an answer to that I will give you credit.